# Magento 2 Data Patch Issue

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm writing a basic module that will create a Bill of Materials for items we sell. The module has three tables: chlorinators, equipment, and chlorinator_equipment.

These tables are generated by db_schema.xml seen below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Setup/Declaration/Schema/etc/schema.xsd">
    <table name="chlorinators" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Chlorinators Table">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="chlorinator_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Chlorinator ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="chlorinator_name" nullable="false" length="1024" comment="Chlorinator Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="boolean" name="has_pump" nullable="false" comment="Chlorinator has pump"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="chlorinator_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
    <table name="equipment" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Equipment Table">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="equipment_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Equipment ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="equipment_name" nullable="false" length="1024" comment="Equipment Name"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="cutsheet_url" nullable="false" default="" comment="Cutsheet URL - Complete"/>
        <column xsi:type="varchar" name="cutsheet_stub" nullable="false" comment="Cutsheet URL - Stub"/>
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="equipment_id"/>
        </constraint>
    </table>
    <table name="chlorinator_equipment" resource="default" engine="innodb" comment="Chlorinator Equipment Relation Table">
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" identity="true" comment="Chlorinator Equipment ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="equipment_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Equipment ID"/>
        <column xsi:type="smallint" name="chlorinator_id" unsigned="true" nullable="false" comment="Chlorinator ID"/>
        <column xsi:type='tinyint' name='quantity' unsigned='true' nullable='false' comment='Quantity' />
        <constraint xsi:type="primary" referenceId="PRIMARY">
            <column name="id"/>
        </constraint>
        <constraint xsi:type='foreign' referenceId="FK_CHLOR_ID" table='chlorinator_equipment' column='chlorinator_id' referenceTable='chlorinators' referenceColumn='chlorinator_id' onDelete='CASCADE'/>
        <constraint xsi:type='foreign' referenceId="FK_EQUIP_ID" table='chlorinator_equipment' column='equipment_id' referenceTable='equipment' referenceColumn='equipment_id' onDelete='CASCADE'/>
    </table>
</schema>
```

Now that I have created the table, I'm looking to input data into the table using Magento's declarative schema. For the purposes of this question, I am only concerned with entering data into the 'chlorinators' table.

I have created a model for the chlorinators (\Jared\Submittal\Model\Chlorinator.php):

```
<?php

namespace Jared\Submittal\Model;

class Chlorinator extends \Magento\Framework\Model\AbstractModel
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('Jared\Submittal\Model\ResourceModel\Chlorinator');
    }
}
```

And a ResourceModel (\Jared\Submittal\Model\ResourceModel\Chlorinator.php):

```
<?php

class Chlorinator extends \Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('chlorinators','chlorinator_id');
    }
}
```

At this point, I'm just trying to insert data into the created table via these models, but I'm not having any luck. I'm using a data patch to try to insert the data, which is below:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Jared\Submittal\Setup\Patch\Data;

    use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;

    /**
     */
    class AddData implements \Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface
         */
        private $moduleDataSetup;
        private $chlorinator;

        /**
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
            \Jared\Submittal\Model\ResourceModel\Chlorinator $chlorinator
        ){
            /**
             * If before, we pass $setup as argument in install/upgrade function, from now we start
             * inject it with DI. If you want to use setup, you can inject it, with the same way as here
             */
            $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
            $this->chlorinator = $chlorinator;
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function apply()
        {
            $chlorinatorData = [];
            $chlorinatorData['chlorinator_id'] = '1';
            $chlorinatorData['chlorinator_name'] = 'chlorinator 1';
            $chlorinatorData['has_pump'] = '1';
            $this->chlorinator->addData($chlorinatorData);
            $this->chlorinator->getResource()->save($this->chlorinator);
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public static function getDependencies()
        {
            /**
             * This is dependency to another patch. Dependency should be applied first
             * One patch can have few dependencies
             * Patches do not have versions, so if in old approach with Install/Ugrade data scripts you used
             * versions, right now you need to point from patch with higher version to patch with lower version
             * But please, note, that some of your patches can be independent and can be installed in any sequence
             * So use dependencies only if this important for you
             */
            return [];
        }

        public function revert()
        {
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->startSetup();
            //Here should go code that will revert all operations from `apply` method
            //Please note, that some operations, like removing data from column, that is in role of foreign key reference
            //is dangerous, because it can trigger ON DELETE statement
            $this->moduleDataSetup->getConnection()->endSetup();
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getAliases()
        {
            /**
             * This internal Magento method, that means that some patches with time can change their names,
             * but changing name should not affect installation process, that's why if we will change name of the patch
             * we will add alias here
             */
            return [];
        }

        public static function getVersion()
        {
            return "1.0.0";
        }
    }
```

I was under the impression that models inherited all the CRUD operations, but when I call create() in AddData.php, I get errors for calling an undefined method. My confusion is exacerbated by the fact that several modules online seem to use identical syntax and work, such as this one:

https://github.com/cedcommerce/Magento2.3-GraphQl/blob/master/Setup/Patch/Data/AddData.php

The error I'm getting has been copied below, please let me know if you see an error in my code that's causing these issues:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Jared\Submittal\Model\ResourceModel\Chlorinator::create() in /var/www/html/app/code/Jared/Submittal/Setup/Patch/Data/AddData.php:63
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/html/vendor/magento/framework/Setup/Patch/PatchApplier.php(162): Jared\Submittal\Setup\Patch\Data\AddData->apply()
#1 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(1081): Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch()
#2 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Model/Installer.php(947): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->handleDBSchemaData()
#3 /var/www/html/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/UpgradeCommand.php(147): Magento\Setup\Model\Installer->installDataFixtures()
#4 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(255): Magento\Setup\Console\Command\UpgradeCommand->execute()
#5 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(1009): Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#6 /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(273): Symfony\Component\Console\Applic in /var/www/html/app/code/Jared/Submittal/Setup/Patch/Data/AddData.php on line 63
{"messages":{"error":[{"code":500,"message":"Fatal Error: 'Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Jared\\Submittal\\Model\\ResourceModel\\Chlorinator::create() in \/var\/www\/html\/app\/code\/Jared\/Submittal\/Setup\/Patch\/Data\/AddData.php:63\nStack trace:\n#0 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/magento\/framework\/Setup\/Patch\/PatchApplier.php(162): Jared\\Submittal\\Setup\\Patch\\Data\\AddData->apply()\n#1 \/var\/www\/html\/setup\/src\/Magento\/Setup\/Model\/Installer.php(1081): Magento\\Framework\\Setup\\Patch\\PatchApplier->applyDataPatch()\n#2 \/var\/www\/html\/setup\/src\/Magento\/Setup\/Model\/Installer.php(947): Magento\\Setup\\Model\\Installer->handleDBSchemaData()\n#3 \/var\/www\/html\/setup\/src\/Magento\/Setup\/Console\/Command\/UpgradeCommand.php(147): Magento\\Setup\\Model\\Installer->installDataFixtures()\n#4 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/console\/Command\/Command.php(255): Magento\\Setup\\Console\\Command\\UpgradeCommand->execute()\n#5 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/console\/Application.php(1009): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Command\\Command->run()\n#6 \/var\/www\/html\/vendor\/symfony\/console\/Application.php(273): Symfony\\Component\\Console\\Applic' in '\/var\/www\/html\/app\/code\/Jared\/Submittal\/Setup\/Patch\/Data\/AddData.php' on line 63","trace":"Trace is not available."}]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example you linked to the `apply` function is using a model, in your code you are using a resource model. So in your `Jared\Submittal\Setup\Patch\Data\AddData` constructor you should be using `\Jared\Submittal\Model\Chlorinator` for `$chlorinator` instead of the resource model you are currently using.

Comment: Thanks. I ended up fixing this by instead using Jared\Submittal\Model\ChlorinatorFactory to inject the factory, then I created a model from the ChlorinatorFactory to add the data to, but your way probably also works.